# Java: code writes strings to txt file but will only read the first entry

Tags: java

I have a question with regards to saving information to a .txt file. The basic problem is that I can save multiple files to the txt file, yet my scanner can only view the first entry. This is done in Java, anyway here is the file upload method:

```
 public void saveFile() throws IOException {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("dataStorage.txt", true);
        //This writes the name of the object to which the file belongs
        // in this case the name would be FILESYS,
        file.write(name+"\n");

        // This writes the number of files in the array
        file.write(files.size()+"\n");

        for (File f: files){
            String fileString = f.getString();
            file.write(fileFile+"\n");
        }

        file.flush();

        file.close();

}
```

Then this is the process I use to call the files from the system:

```
public void loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {       
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("dataStorage.txt"));       
        name = scanner.nextLine();
        int numFiles = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println(numFiles);

        for (int i = 0; i<numFiles; i++){          
            String currentFileString = scanner.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println(currentFileString);
            Movie currentFile = new File(currentFileString);
            files.add(currentFile);
        }

    }
```

I have tried manually changing the first number int he txt file to two or more but it still only reads the first one (Depending on how I alter it, it can print the whole text file as just one entry). Sorry if this is a poorly worded question (first one) any help would be greatly appreciated! btw file is only a filler to under stand the issue and simplify it.

Comment: `Movie currentFile = new File(...)`? Is `Movie` an extension of `File` that you made?

Comment: What is the content of the file? Also, shouldn't this: `file.write(fileFile+"\n");` be `file.write(fileString+"\n");`. Another thing, according to the API `File` does not have a `getString` method. Is `File` a custom class?

Comment: Don't use `Scanner` to read lines of a text file, it has some major processing overhead. Use a `BufferedReader` instead.

Comment: Sorry, some clarification, movie was what file should be, I changed it to make sense. IDK why tho. file has name, year, etc File is a custom class with a getString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loadFile()` method will only read one "save block" (name, count, values), but the `saveFile()` method appends to any existing file, so any save after the first will never be loaded.

Remove `, true` from the `FileWriter` constructor.

---

Let's say you have:

```
name = "ABC"
files = [ "Hello", "World" ]
```

Calling `saveFile()` will create `dataStorage.txt` with:

```
ABC
2
Hello
World
```

Restarting your program and calling `loadFile()` will get that back into memory.

Adding another entry to `files`:

```
name = "ABC"
files = [ "Hello", "World", "Foo" ]
```

Calling `saveFile()` will **append** to `dataStorage.txt` leaving it as:

```
ABC
2
Hello
World
ABC
3
Hello
World
Foo
```

Restarting your program and calling `loadFile()` will only get the **first** block:

```
name = "ABC"
files = [ "Hello", "World" ]
```

Comment: The issue is if I do that, then I can only write one file to the txt, I need to be able to append to it.

Comment: Well, as I said, your load method only loads one set of files, so appending another "set" will not be loaded by that load method.